# How to export path breadcrumbs

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I see written everywhere that Path breadcrumbs https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs can be exported via features. But I am unable to see any Path breadcrumb option when I'm creating a feature, nor I see any export thing in Path breadcrumbs settings.

Do you know where/how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Features:** Check if you have Path Breadcrumbs module checked in Features Settings (screenshot below). If it was checked and you still do not see it in the Features components list than something else is amiss.

[image]

---

**Export:** As for the direct **export of Path Breadcrumbs**, you can find "export" link while clicking on "edit" in path breadcrumbs actions list (screenshot below)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh I see the export option (in my defence, I am working with a Japanese web site). So that is one thing. But I still don't see anything when I'm creating a new feature, even though I made sure I have the checkbox checked as in your first screenshot. But I guess I can manually create a file with the export option and put it inside the feature, as like views works with features?

Comment: @Francesc you could do it manually similar to views. The hook to add the export of breadcrumbs settings would be `hook_path_breadcrumbs_settings_info()`. Still a mystery why path breadcrumbs are not shown as a component..